# nvarchar needs to contain only english or georgian letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, check-constraints

My constraint: 
`(datalength([Firstname])>=(2) AND datalength([Firstname])<=(50) AND (NOT [Firstname] like '%[^a-zA-Z]%' AND NOT [Firstname] like N'%[^ა-ზ]%'))`

Adding first name with Georgian letters causes error: [image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Please don't post images with tiny text. Code and errors are text and should be posted as (formatted) `text`.

Comment: What value are you trying to insert into Firstname?

Comment: What characters are you trying to limit your value to? Also why are you checking that the datalength is less than *something*, you can stop the name being more than 25 characters by making the column an `nvarchar(25)`. If, however, you're limiting the characters to only alpha characters, and a few soecial characters, then why use an `nvarchar` at all, when a `varchar` will suffice?

Comment: What I'm trying to insert into firstname isn't really a concern e.g:  anything with ONLY English letters or with ONLY Georgian letters must be inserted.

Comment: What is an "English" letter? Just A-z with no accents? What would you expect to happen with someone who *does* have an accent in their name; not allow them to use your system? What about people who have a special character in their name? If you are only permitting A-Z, again, why use `nvarchar`, when there is clearly no need?

Comment: @larnu I'm permitting ENGLISH AND GEORGIAN letters, examples: "abc", "def", "GHI", "jKl", "MnO" OR "აბგ", "დევ", "ზთ", "კუილო" and etc

Comment: I think it's just a matter of getting the NOT's and AND's in the right place.  It would be a lot easier to help if your query was text instead of a picture.

Comment: @DavidDubois (datalength([Firstname])>=(2) AND datalength([Firstname])<=(50) AND (NOT [Firstname] like '%[^a-zA-Z]%' AND NOT [Firstname] like N'%[^ა-ზ]%'))

Comment: You should put that in the question.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the proper first and last Georgian letters according to your collation?  When I test it on my machine, I get  ზ  precedes  კ  .  Maybe you are using a different collation.

Comment: @DavidDubois you are a hero mate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Georgian names, but perhaps your choice of first and last letters isn't appropriate for your collation.  Perhaps the best idea is to just list all the characters allowed. Instead of:

```
N'%[^ა-ზ]%'
```

Perhaps something like this:

```
 N'%[^ႠႡႢႣႤႥႦႧႨႩႪႫႬႭႮႯႰႱႲႳႴႵႶႷႸႹႺ'
+N'ႻႼႽႾႿჀჁჂჃჄჅჇჍაბგდევზთიკლმნოპჟრს'
+N'ტუფქღყშჩცძწჭხჯჰჱჲჳჴჵჶჷჸჹჺჼჽჾჿⴀⴁⴂⴃⴄⴅ'
+N'ⴆⴇⴈⴉⴊⴋⴌⴍⴎⴏⴐⴑⴒⴓⴔⴕⴖⴗⴘⴙⴚⴛⴜⴝⴞⴟⴠⴡⴢ'
+N'ⴣⴤⴥⴧⴭ]%'
```

Other than that, make sure that all your logical operators, `AND`'s, `NOT`'s and `OR`'s are appropriate.

You may want to consider if this limitation is appropriate for your needs.  Names of humans can be more diverse than you might ever think.  Google "`Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names`"